# Regular expression, repetitive string it does not work

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$string = '<td class="t_ip">85.185.244.101</td><td class="t_port">           <script type="text/javascript">           //<![CDATA[             document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225);           //]]>           </script>         </td><td class="t_type">         4         </td>';

$regex = "/<td class=\"t_ip\">\\s*((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?:.|\\n)*<td class=\"t_port\">(?:.|\\n)*\^([0-9]{1,5})(?:.|\\n)*<td class=\"t_type\">\\s*([0-9])/";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
$newString = $matches[1] . ':' . $matches[2] . ' ' . $matches[3];
print_r($newString);
```

Regular expression:

```
$regex = "/<td class=\"t_ip\">\\s*((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?:.|\\n)*<td class=\"t_port\">(?:.|\\n)*\^([0-9]{1,5})(?:.|\\n)*<td class=\"t_type\">\\s*([0-9])/";
```

To extract the information in this way:

```
85.185.244.101:22088 4
```

But if repeated more than twice does not work

```
$string = '<td class="t_ip">85.185.244.101</td><td class="t_port"><script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225);//]]></script></td><td class="t_type">4</td><td class="t_ip">85.185.244.101</td><td class="t_port"><script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225);//]]></script></td><td class="t_type">4</td><td class="t_ip">85.185.244.101</td><td class="t_port"><script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225);//]]></script></td><td class="t_type">4</td>';
```

That would have to change to make it work?

Comment: Where does `22088` come from?

Comment: <![CDATA[document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225)

Comment: That says `47225`. If js is evaluating that and getting 22088 PHP won't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a parser rather than a regex, regex with HTML don't go well. You could do something like this:

```
<?php
$string = '<td class="t_ip">85.185.244.101</td><td class="t_port">           <script type="text/javascript">           //<![CDATA[             document.write(HttpSocks^Xinemara^47225);           //]]>           </script>         </td><td class="t_type">         4         </td>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$cells = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($cells as $cell) {
if(preg_match('/\bt_(ip|type)\b/', $cell->getAttribute('class'), $type)){
     echo $type[1] . "=" . trim($cell->nodeValue) . "\n";
}
}
```

Output:

```
ip=85.185.244.101
type=4
```

If you need to validate the IP you could add in something like:

```
if($type[1] == 'ip') {
if(filter_var($cell->nodeValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
     echo 'valid ip' . $cell->nodeValue;
} else {
     echo 'invalid ip' . $cell->nodeValue;
}
}
```

I don't see where in your provided string `22088` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/<td class=\"t_ip\">\\s*?((?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?:.|\\n)*?<td class=\"t_port\">(?:.|\\n)*?\^([0-9]{1,5})(?:.|\\n)*?<td class=\"t_type\">\\s*?([0-9])/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

$data = array();
if ($matches) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $data[] = $matches[1][$i] . ':' . $matches[2][$i] . ' ' . $matches[3][$i];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```